# Перевод даты из формата: "5 минут назад, сегодня в 22.00, вчера в 19:45" в UnixTime?На языке C#

Tags: c#, время, конвертация

Подскажите пожалуйста, как осуществить конвертацию даты из формата: "**5 минут назад**, **сегодня в 22:00**, **вчера в 19:45**" в UnixTime? На языке C#
Спасибо!

Comment: Вы полностью опишите входной формат. «За 10 минут до КВН» — подходит? «Последняя пятница, 13-ое, в позапрошлом году, полночь» — подходит?

Comment: @VladD, судя по всему, тут просто 3 разных указателя на время, описываемых словами. И формата у них может всего два - `X {секунд, минут, часов} назад`(относительное время) и `{сегодня, вчера, позавчера} в XX:XX`(относительный день и точное время)

Comment: Ребят, это собственно вконтакте, в любой группе, если мы зайдем, увидим что время, когда был размещен пост, в начале ленты, имеет именно такой формат. Мне его нужно преобразовать в нормальный формат, в идеальном случае в Unixtime.

Comment: @Александр: Вы же понимаете, что описание формата «такой как в ВКонтакте» ничем не лучше описания даты «за неделю перед Пасхой». Угадывать правила, по которым ВКонтакте форматирует даты, — достаточно сложная задача.

Comment: @VladD а там и угадывать не надо, из нормального DateTime получить вид "в полнолуние за пять минут до восхода" труда не составит, а вот расшифровать обратно - задачка не проще машинного перевода с японского на якутский =)

Comment: А если речь идёт о вконтакте, то там в разметке сайта есть ваше unix time: `<span class="rel_date rel_date_needs_update" time="1458925515" abs_time="сегодня в 20:05">два часа назад</span>`. `time="1458925515"` — то, что вам нужно. Но вообще-то, вы не должны пытаться заскрейпить сайт (это наверняка ещё и противоречит правилам использования). Воспользуйтесь официальным API.

Comment: Спасибо за отзывчивость, видимо не везде есть unixtime. Это я заметил, после глубокого анализа, я могу сказать, что, порой данное значение не соответствует реальности. Даже с учетом смещения, в 2 или 3 часа, уже не помню. Вот к примеру группа : http:// vk.com/ wellarussia (пробелы удалить).